# Time complexity of uniform-cost search

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, artificial-intelligence, big-o

I am reading the book *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*. I came across this sentence describing the time complexity of uniform cost search:

> Uniform-cost search is guided by path costs rather than depths, so its
>   complexity is not easily characterized in terms of b and d. Instead,
>   let C be the cost of the optimal solution, and assume that every
>   action costs at least ε. Then the algorithm’s worst-case time and
>   space complexity is O(b^(1+C/ε)), which can be much greater than b^d.

As to my understanding, C is the cost of the optimal solution, and every action costs at least ε, so that C/ε would be the number of steps taken to the destination. But I don't know how the complexity is derived.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the branching factor is b, every time you expand out a node, you will encounter k more nodes.  Therefore, there are

- 1 node at level 0,
- b nodes at level 1,
- b<sup>2</sup> nodes at level 2,
- b<sup>3</sup> nodes at level 3,
- ...
- b<sup>k</sup> nodes at level k.

So let's suppose that the search stops after you reach level k.  When this happens, the total number of nodes you'll have visited will be

> 1 + b + b<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sup>k</sup> = (b<sup>k+1</sup> - 1) / (b - 1)

That equality follows from the sum of a geometric series.  It happens to be the case that b<sup>k+1</sup> / (b - 1) = O(b<sup>k</sup>), so if your goal node is in layer k, then you have to expand out O(b<sup>k</sup>) total nodes to find the one you want.

If C is your destination cost and each step gets you ε closer to the goal, the number of steps you need to take is given by C / ε + 1.  The reason for the +1 is that you start at distance 0 and end at C / ε, so you take steps at distances

> 0, ε, 2ε, 3ε, ..., (C / ε)ε

And there are 1 + C / ε total steps here.  Therefore, there are 1 + C / ε layers, and so the total number of states you need to expand is O(b<sup>(1 + C / ε)</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. One thing I don't understand is the number of nodes been expanded at each level since to the uniform-cost search, nodes at each level may not been fully expanded, there may be only some of them been expanded. It is more like a breadth-first search that will expand all the nodes in each level.

Comment: @photosynthesis- That's true.  However, in UCS, you won't expand out any nodes in a layer at distance (k+1)e until you've expanded out all the nodes in a layer at distance ke.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If there's a graph with 5 layers, each with branching factor 3. There exists a path from the root to the goal with all the cost at 1, so the total cost would be 5. At the same time, all the other paths except the goal path have cost at 100 for each. So for UCS here, it will always expand the "goal path", because from the root to the goal, with each incrementation, the total value of that path would always lower than the others. So I think for UCS, it will not fully expand the nodes at each layer. Is that correct? thanks!

Comment: @photosynthesis- Yes, that's correct.  From your problem description, I thought that you said that each action cost *exactly* epsilon rather than *at least* epsilon, though rereading it I realize this isn't the case.  However, from a *worst-case* perspective, the analysis is correct.

Comment: Do you mean the worst case of UCS would be that the incremental values of each step is the same, so at this situation, it would be same as the breadth-first search?thanks

Comment: @photosynthesis- Yep!  Exactly.

Comment: @templatetypedef I think your answer is slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

templatetypedef's answer is somewhat incorrect. The +1 has nothing to do with the fact that the starting depth is 0. If every step cost is at least ε > 0, and the cost of optimal solution is C, then the maximum depth of the optimal solution occurs at floor(C / ε). But the worst case time/space complexity is in fact O(b<sup>(1+floor(C/ε)</sup>). The +1 arises because in UCS, we only check whether a node is a goal when we select it for expansion, and not when we generate it (this is to ensure optimality). So in the worst case, we could potentially generate the entire level of nodes that comes after the goal node's residing level (this explains the +1). In comparison, BFS applies the goal test when nodes are generated, so there is no corresponding +1 factor. This is a very important point that he missed.

Comment: You're slightly incorrect too. In the worst case, we generate all the nodes in the level of the goal node. This is at floor(C / ε) + 1. We can't check for goal at the level floor(C / ε) because we don't know that the goal state will be selected next to expand.

Comment: @LearningMath what exactly are you saying is incorrect in the answer? It seems like you're just restating what the answer is saying, that the +1 occurs because all the nodes at the level after the level of the goal node might be generated before the algorithm terminates.